# Windows 10 Crashes Everytime

Tags: windows, installation

Being excited about Windows 10, I updated my PC yesterday night (Dell 1500 series, 64 bit) to Windows 10 from Windows 8.1 (Pre-installed). Little did I know that this will be so bad (my PC has become useless). **Now my PC boots but after sometime, no matter what I do (like open Edge), it crashes with the message:**

*:(

Your PC Ran into a Problem and needs to restart.
We are just collecting some error info and then, we'll restart for you.*

I don't know what to do, the PC doesn't even give me enough time to backup my data so that I could install other OS.
Please help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 lets you revert to your previous OS within 1 month. Go to settings -> Update and Security and Choose Revert back to Windows 8/8.1/7.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I couldn't get the computer to stay up long enough to access settings and by divine intervention found this fix:

http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4097-windows-10-go-back-previous-build.html

When I did it this way I got stuck on restart and cut the power, I had found a post about this and wanted to paste it but cannot find it anymore. Anyway, I had to cut the power and start the computer twice and on the second start everything reverted to 8.1 and my files were ok.

I hope this helps!